# Using Fragments In MainActivity For NavigationDrawerFragment in Android Studio

Tags: android-fragments, navigation, panel

I have been trying to Design an App That has PANEL like Google Drawers.

• MainActivity

```
package skynet.com.testnavigationpanel;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    Intent i=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        // populate the navigation drawer
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData("Falcon Shield", "We Protect Your Device!", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shieldavatar));
    }

    public void login_signup(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.log_in:
                i=new Intent(this,Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 500);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
            case R.id.sign_up:
                i=new Intent(this,Signup.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 500);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position)
    {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onSectionAttached(int anInt) {

    }
}
```

•NavigationDrawerFragment

```
package skynet.com.testnavigationpanel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public List getMenu() {
        List items= new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.homeFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.loginFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_login)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.signupFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_signup)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.settingFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_setting )));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.shareFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_share )));
        items.add(new NavigationItem(getString(R.string.aboutFrag),getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_about )));
        return items;
    }
    public void showBackButton(){
        if(getActivity()instanceof ActionBarActivity){
            ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
     */
    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = (View) getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId).getParent();
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
        ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void setUserData(String user, String email, Bitmap avatar) {
        ImageView avatarContainer = (ImageView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
        ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail)).setText(email);
        ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername)).setText(user);
        avatarContainer.setImageDrawable(new RoundImage(avatar));
    }

    public View getGoogleDrawer() {
        return mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.googleDrawer);
    }

    public static class RoundImage extends Drawable {
        private final Bitmap mBitmap;
        private final Paint mPaint;
        private final RectF mRectF;
        private final int mBitmapWidth;
        private final int mBitmapHeight;

        public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
            mRectF = new RectF();
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            mPaint.setShader(shader);

            mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
            mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
            super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
            mRectF.set(bounds);
        }

        @Override
        public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
            if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
                mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
                invalidateSelf();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
            mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        }

        @Override
        public int getOpacity() {
            return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
            return mBitmapWidth;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
            return mBitmapHeight;
        }

        public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
            invalidateSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
            mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
            invalidateSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void setDither(boolean dither) {
            mPaint.setDither(dither);
            invalidateSelf();
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
        }

    }
}
```

Kindly Guide me in Mentioning the Right code into Below Method of MainActivity.

```
onNavigationDrawerItemSelect(int position)
 {
   //codes for fragments That i dont Know how to write
 }
```

My Fragment Class(Please Check the Code if its Right or needs to be changed)

```
    package skynet.com.testnavigationpanel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Evan on 28-Dec-15.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(){
        HomeFragment fragment=new HomeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public HomeFragment()
    {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
        return rootView;

    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity)activity).onSectionAttached(1);
    }

}
```

Same Goes with my Other fragments for login, signup, about, share, etc..with Relevant Changes in Layout id and Names.

Devs, Kindly Help ! Thanks

Comment: No one wants to download your zip file. Please post the relevant sections of your code. Also, CAPS LOCK ISN'T NECESSARY TO GET YOUR POINT ACROSS

Comment: Well, M new Here.. Thanks for notifying! I'll put relevant Code